# use angular-fontawesome SVG icons in GoJS

Tags: angular, svg, font-awesome, gojs, angular-fontawesome

Under the [usage](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage.md) page and other documentation material of angular-fontawesome library, I could not find any references to suggest how any SVG icon can be extracted/referred from the library.

How to to use the SVG icon from the library under GoJS canvas?

Comment: Not familiar with GoJS, but we have a guide on how to [render icon into an SVG string](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/guide/advanced-uses.md#include-icon-in-the-markup-passed-as-a-string-to-a-javascript-library) or if you don't need any of the styling features, you can manually compose a [simplified SVG tag](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/35#issuecomment-418216368).

Comment: If you want to show an SVG path string and control its fill and stroke colors, use a **Shape** class in GoJS and set its **Shape.geometry** property to that SVG path string, prepended with an "F" if you want the areas to be filled.  More info at: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/shapes.html#Geometry.  Sample at: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/icons.html